# How to write the nested dictionaries into SQL table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write the nested dictionaries into SQL Table in a single row.

I want to join the (User_ID ) Dictionary values and Nested Dictionary (V.Values()) into single row.

In (V.Values()) has both strings and integer datatypes in the nested dictionary. So I've combined as list and assigned into values variable.

I'm getting error in SQL query execution, I've tried some of the methods still also getting errors.

If run the code I'm getting error like **ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement**

Working code : Part of code use to write the dictionaries into SQL

```
    import mysql.connector as conn

    db = conn.connect(
        host ="Localhost",
        user ="root",
        passwd ="admin",
        )

    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00")

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    database = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details ( User_ID int(10), Name VARCHAR(255), Age int(3), Occupation VARCHAR(255), Department VARCHAR(255), Salary int(10), Address VARCHAR(255) ) ")

    user_details = {}

    while True:
    user_input = input(" You're Operation Please ( New / View ) Details : ").lower()

    if user_input == 'new':
        create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
        user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
        user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
        user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age
        user_occupation = input(" Enter the users occupation : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Occupation'] = user_occupation
        user_department = input(" user department : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Department'] = user_department
        user_income = int(input(" Enter the salary details : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Salary'] = user_income
        user_address = input(" Enter the Address details ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Address'] = user_address

        print(f" New User account {create_user_ID} has been successfully created")
        for detail in user_details.items():
            print(detail)

        for k,v in user_details.items():
            columns = ", ".join(["User_ID"] + list(v.keys()))
            values = ", ".join([k] + [str(v) for v in v.values()])

            sql = "INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
            ', '.join(columns),
            ', '.join(['%s'] * len(v)));

            cursor.execute(sql, list(values))
            db.commit()

        process = input(" Do you want to continue the Account creation process (YES / NO ) : ").lower()
        if process == 'no':
            break

    elif user_input == 'view':
        user_input = input("Enter the User_ID :")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE USER_ID = '%s'" % (user_input))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        print(record)
        break

    else:
        print(" Please enter the proper command to execute (new / view)")
```

Code - Output( User-defined Values)

```
('0001': {'Name': 'User_00', 'Age': 22, 'Occupation': 'Test', 'Department': 'Test', 'Salary': 0, 'Address': 'World'})
```

SQL Output (For Example)

```
User_ID  User_name    User_Age    User_Occupation

1101     Test_User    Test_Age    Test_Occupation
```

Let me know any solution for this problem.

Does anyone can solve my problem, it is really appreciable. Thanks for your time in Advance !!

Comment: Can you print the sql query and post it as well?

Comment: sql = "INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
    ', '.join(columns),
    ', '.join(['%s'] * len(v)));

Comment: Or you want the queries for the created Database & tables

Comment: Yeah I do mean the variable sql but printed out, when the query has build. It should just be a full sql statement.

Comment: I've updated the code now.. Please have a look now

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. You have to put print(sql) below the variable. And run the code. Then post here what the print said. (This way you and me can check if the sql query was builded correctly :) )

Comment: sry misunderstood, Now Got it

Comment: INSERT INTO Details (U, s, e, r, _, I, D, ,,  , N, a, m, e, ,,  , A, g, e, ,,  , O, c, c, u, p, a, t, i, o, n, ,,  , D, e, p, a, r, t, m, e, n, t, ,,  , S, a, l, a, r, y, ,,  , A, d, d, r, e, s, s) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

Comment: Why are you creating a nested dictionary with User ID as a master key when you’ll just be inserting that individual’s User ID straight into the database afterwards? Personally, I’d reconsider the data structures/process flow you’re using. A nested dictionary is adding complexity where it doesn’t seem to be needed. Seems like you are running the db insert for each new user, so you can collect the data into one dictionary, run the insert on a simple dictionary, then you could add the data to a big master dictionary (with user is as main key) afterwards if you still need to...

Comment: it is printed like this

Comment: @dijksterhuis Actually I'm python practioner, This is my demo project for certification. They asked to me do using nested dictionary only

Comment: Sorry for the late response, as you can see your query is not build correctly. (it puts a comma behind every character). I guess because you loop it once to much in the creation of the values. You can check this by printing this out. Anyhow this amount of comma's results in having a lot of parameters.. Adjust your variable values!